# How to use Turkit for MTURK?

Tags: javascript, soap, https, mechanicalturk

I am trying to use the package [Turkit](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/turkit/) on windows7 and just trying to get the sample code given in the package working.

```
print("Hello World")
print("Your balance is: " + mturk.getAccountBalance())
```

And I have specified my awsAccessKeyID and awsSecretAccessKey in properties file.

But I got the following error:

> org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ERROR 500: 
>   aws:Client.NonSecureRequestThis request must be made over a secure channel. You must use 'https' rather than 'http'.72aff2a1-4ba4-40a6-beb3-b65deafd3945

I am thinking there might be something wrong with my internet connection setting or I didn't install something that is required by this package. Could anyone help me figure out what's going wrong here?

Thanks！

Comment: this should be fixed in version 0.2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is as Isaac said - they started enforcing "HTTPS" requests, so until they push out a fix (aka use HTTPS) in order to use it you'd have to download the source code and change it there. You can download the source code  [here](http://code.google.com/p/turkit/source/checkout).

Unless you need it shortly, I'd wait for fix (or contact them and ask them to fix it sooner)

Answer (score 0):

The Mechanical Turk team recently started enforcing that all API calls must be made over "https" instead of "http" for security reasons.  You just need to change the request URL to "https" and it should work.

Cheers, 
Isaac