# Any good free framework to use with Amazon Mechanical Turk?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am wondering there are any good free frameworks to use with Amazon Mechanical Turk. I have been building the web site by hand but I am hoping to save some time by using a framework. The only one that I found is [Turkit](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/turkit/), but I am wondering if there are other options out there (especially because Turkit seems to require [a fix as a result of a recent change on Amazon's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526840/how-to-use-turkit-for-mturk)).

I am looking for something that is non-platform specific. Our project right now is mostly about human annotation (of text), but flexibility of the framework to easily incorporate graphics would be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

btw, that required fix has been made (in version 0.2.7 of TurKit)